# How do I find uses of a word in Ecclesiastical Latin?

Tags: resource-request, ecclesiastical-latin

If I want to find a citation for a word in Classical(-ish) Latin, I might go to [the Packhum Corpus](http://latin.packhum.org/search), put in the stem, and weed through any spurious results.

But suppose I want to know how (or if) a word was used in specifically Christian Latin. How would I find this?

Comment: I'd search the Vulgate and Denzinger

Comment: @Rafael Is there a good/easy way to search the Vulgate, like there is for the Packhum corpus? Even a plain TXT version would be useful (I can then use normal corpus tools on it), but I haven't found such a thing.

Comment: http://vulsearch.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/vulsearch not as good as one would expect, but it's a starting point

Comment: I'm afraid most of such databases are subscription-based - see, instance, http://apps.brepolis.net/BrepolisPortal/default.aspx (Thesaurus Patrum Latinorum etc.), also http://www.brepols.net/Pages/BrowseBySeries.aspx?TreeSeries=LLT-O

Comment: I second VulSearch—use it on a daily basis.

Answer (score 1):

Google Books search. There is already a vast number of scanned late scholastic and other post-Classical Latin books there.

Comment: Is there a way to narrow it down to only Ecclesiastical Latin works?